# Buttons are wrapping up for me on a particular question

Tags: bug, design

Am not sure whether its just for me or the normal account users as well, but on this particular question, [what is the significance of lighting camphor infront of god?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3065/124), buttons are wrapping up in two lines...

[image]

Am on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.5, Windows 7, 1366*768 Resolution.

Comment: There's no wrapping for me.  I tried the link on my iPhone, iPad, and Windows XP computer running Chrome.  Does the wrapping persist even when you're logged out?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan You don't have a `mod` button so may be :)

Comment: As I am not a mod, I copied the actions through developer tools and I can see the same issue. [Link](http://i.imgur.com/N8IkLD9.png)

Comment: I think it would be better if this question is asked on Meta.SE. (_lots of community mods can be found there_)

Comment: Took me ages to find the dupe because it was marked as a feature request. Sigh. :)